# Is there a particular café that does anime coffee art?

Tags: tourism

I've seen a lot of coffee art of anime characters on social media, and I'd love to get my own anime-coffee - or even find out the location so I can see more of their art.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there somewhere specific that serves these anime coffees or is this just individuals creating the art?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Coffee art is commonly refered to as "Latte art" (ラテ・アート in japanese). By searching this term in japanese along with "anime" (アニメ) on the internet, you will be able to find many results (such as [this blog](http://natsucafe.blog120.fc2.com/) where you will find many anime latte arts), and even many tutorials to make your own latte arts!

If you want to go see by yourself in a café, you can probably use this [article](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2135358908679594101?&page=1) as reference as it lists many recommended places in Japan where you can enjoy latte art. However, arts such as characters representations usually require lot of preparation/work/tries, so I would not expect too complex arts by going there in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

One of the latte art cafés has started putting watermarks on their images, now I can tell everyone about this amazing place, which is the source of a lot of the images currently circulating

[Belcorno](http://www.belcorno.jp/_latte_art/index.html)

It is a pizzaria that also does latte art. **By reservation only**, for about 1050 Yen.

[Here is their facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/BELCORNO/)

[image]

Along with this mix they have entire sets of characters from series like IdolM@ster, etc.